# OLS Summation form to matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

Let me preface by saying I'm not particularly a mathematician. Just a curious engineer.
I'm trying to build an understanding for the matrix form of OLS, by developing it from the summation form, which I understand. I've gotten this far:
$$Y_1=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1$$
$$Y_2=\beta_0+\beta_1x_2$$
$$Y_3=\beta_0+\beta_1x_3$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\sum_{i}^{n}y_i=\beta_0\sum_{i}^{n}1+\beta_1\sum_{i}^{n}x_i$$
$$(multiply\ both\ sides\ by\ x_i)$$
$$\sum_{i}^{n}{x_iy}_i=\beta_0\sum_{i}^{n}x_i+\beta_1\sum_{i}^{n}x_i^2$$
$$(Represent\ with\ matrices)$$
$$X^TY=\left[\begin{matrix}\sum_{i}^{n}x_i&\sum_{i}^{n}x_i^2\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\beta_0\\\beta_1\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$X^TY=\left[\begin{matrix}\sum_{i}^{n}x_i&\sum_{i}^{n}x_i^2\\\end{matrix}\right]\beta$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$???$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$X^TY={(X}^TX)\beta$$
I'm somewhat sure the top part is true, and the bottom part definitely should be true, so what's the missing piece to get from the top to the bottom?

How does $\left[\begin{matrix}\sum_{i}^{n}x_i&\sum_{i}^{n}x_i^2\\\end{matrix}\right]$ equal ${(X}^TX)$?

Is there some linear algebra rule that I'm missing?

I would figure it out myself but I'm not sure what to search for, every result I've found just shows the process for both starting and ending with the matrix form.

Comment: There is a missing equation containing $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$ after "Represent with matrices".

Comment: @d.k.o. I'm not sure I understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The matrix in the middle should be:
\begin{bmatrix}n&\sum_{i}^{n}x_i \\\sum_{i}^{n}x_i&\sum_{i}^{n}x_i^2 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: @d.k.o. Sure, but why? Whenever I converted from the summation to the matrix multiplication, I used this idea: $ax+by=\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]$, where $a, b$ are the summations and $x, y$ are the Betas. Where is the 2x2 matrix coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it helpful to look in detail at what happens in the case that we have 3 data points. First, the original equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1\\
y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_2\\
y_3 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_3\
\end{cases}  \implies
Y = \overbrace{\pmatrix{1 & x_1\\ 1 & x_2\\ 1 & x_3}}^X \pmatrix{\beta_0\\\beta_1}
$$
Next, the least squares version:
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1) + (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_2) + (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_3)\\
x_1y_1 + x_2 y_2  + x_3 y_3 = x_1(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1) + x_2(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_2) + x_3(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_3) 
\end{cases}  \implies\\
\begin{cases}
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 3\beta_0 + (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)\beta_1\\
x_1y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3y_3 = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)\beta_0 + (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)\beta_1
\end{cases} \implies\\
\overbrace{\pmatrix{y_1+y_2+y_3\\x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3}}^{X^TY} = \overbrace{\pmatrix{3 & x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}^{X^TX}\pmatrix{\beta_0 \\ \beta _1}.
$$

Comment: I think I'm starting to see part of the issue. The first two lines in my work are taken from resources I found online. I was interpreting them as Step 1 / Step 2, when I think I was supposed to interpret them as a system of equations.

Comment: Right, now I see where you were coming from. To get to the least squares equation, we go from the system of equations for $y_1,\dots,y_n$ to the (generally much smaller) system equations for $y_1 + \dots + y_n$ and $x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\boldsymbol{X}=[X_1 \quad \cdots \quad X_k]$ is a matrix with $k$ columns, then
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{X}^{\top}\boldsymbol{X}&=\begin{bmatrix}
X_1^{\top} \\
\vdots \\
X_k^{\top}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 & \cdots & X_k\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
X_1^{\top}X_1 & \cdots & X_1^{\top}X_k \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
X_k^{\top}X_1  & \cdots & X_k^{\top}X_k
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

---

In your case,
\begin{align}
X_1&=[1 \quad \cdots\quad 1]^{\top} \quad\text{and}\\
X_2&=[x_1\quad\cdots\quad x_n]^{\top}.
\end{align}
Thus, $X_1^{\top}X_1=n$, $X_1^{\top}X_2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and $X_2^{\top}X_2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.